# Running docker containers on servers(Production line)

Tags: webserver, docker

Is it possible to run docker directly on the server i.e. production server with an OS?

As I wanted to host a website on my server (hardware), I am curious if I can make a docker container and run it on the hardware on ubuntu server.

Can anyone tell me if its possible and if it's possible what problems I might face?

Whenever I search on google it always shows result about windows server. 
 https://blog.docker.com/2016/09/dockerforws2016/

Comment: might be helpful https://shivab.com/blog/docker/2019/01/10/introduction-to-docker-and-containerization/

Answer (score 0):

As in without any OS installed? No, it's not possible - Docker requires an OS to run. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46285198/run-docker-without-host-os) on StackOverflow for more details.

Edit: 
I'm not sure if that is what you mean, but you cannot run Docker as a bare-metal [hypervisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor) since Docker containers do not contain a kernel - rather they use the underlying OS's kernel to run - see explanation on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)#Operation). The closes you can get to running Docker as a bare-metal hypervisor is to use [Container Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container_Linux_by_CoreOS#CoreOS) as a host OS.

Comment: No sorry you misinterpreted with an operating system(Server like ubuntu server) and running docker over it

Comment: Then what do you mean by 'directly'? You can only use Linux containers on Docker on Linux OS and they do not require a VM or anything of the sort.

Comment: Directly meant deploying our container on the hardware and ofcourse with an operating system and i know they dont require vm

Comment: See my edit for more info